# Using a variable's value to use that variables value

Tags: bash

Alright, so I'm trying to use a variables value to then use the value of that variable inorder to get the value of that variable.

So, my `script` takes `$1` as a message, and then takes `$2` as the color in which to print that out as.

```
#!/bin/bash

# TAKES $1 as MSG and $2 as COLOR.
export black='echo -e "\E[30;47m"'
export red='echo -e "\E[31;47m"'
export green='echo -e "\E[32;47m"'
export yellow='echo -e "\E[33;47m"'
export blue='echo -e "\E[34;47m"'
export magenta='echo -e "\E[35;47m"'
export cyan='echo -e "\E[36;47m"'
export white='echo -e "\E[37;47m"'

# VARIABLES
export color="$2"              # Set Color
export message="$1"            # Set MSG

# Use $color for what variable to substitute with, so we get the echos.
# Previously tried \$$color to get $whatever_$2_was but it wouldn't get the value.
\$$color

echo "$message"                # Echo Message.
tput sgr0                      # Reset to normal.
```

**It'd be called as:**

```
USAGE: cecho "MESSAGE" color
```

So, basically the scripts point is to color `$message` with whatever `$2` equals.

Anyidea how to either:

**1.** Get the value of the variable with the `$2` name,

**or**

**2.** Better way of writing this `script`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up indirection (fourth paragraph of [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

```
${!color}
```

If `color=white`, this will generate the string from `$white`, which is what you're after, I think.  You could also look up the `eval` command, but it is generally not as desirable (more dangerous than) the `${!color}` notation.

As to better ways to write the script: I'd defer the `echo -e` until I used the colours, and I wouldn't export the variables unless you're planning to dot (`.`) or `source` the script:

```
black='\E[30;47m'
...
white='\E[37;47m'

...
color="$2"
...

echo -e "${!color}"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and Worked amazingly, thanks for the solution and the tips!